# tableview in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to know that in ios7, Is it use the prepareForSegue method instead of the didSelectAtIndexPath method?

if yes, how can I change the follow code that can run in ios7?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *tempSqlStatement = @"";
NSString *tempString = @"%";
databaseName = @"TCMdb8.sql";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                databaseName];
if (buttonNum == 0) {

    Function1DetailViewController *function1DetailViewController =
   [[Function1DetailViewController alloc] initWithKey:[listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] type:@"1"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:function1DetailViewController animated:YES];
}else if (buttonNum != 0){
    if (buttonNum == 1) {
        tableTitle = @"xxxx";
        tempSqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name from Medicine where stroke ='%@' ORDER BY length(name) ASC", [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         function1SQLStatement = [tempSqlStatement UTF8String];
  }
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readFromDatabase];
    [tableList reloadData];
    buttonNum = 0;

}
```

Comment: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue` are both used in iOS7.  They do different things.  Moreover, they've both been used since before iOS7 and their usage hasn't changed from iOS6 to iOS7.

Given that you're pushing view controllers with the `pushViewController:` method and not actually using segues, you'll never see the `prepareForSegue` method called, and as far as I know, your code will still work in iOS7.
If it doesn't work, you should explain what's not working in greater detail.

Comment: You didn't need to do anything unless you are using storyboards as prepareForSegue gives you an opportunity to pass values to the view controller that you are going to transition to. Based on your above implementation, I can see that you have custom initialiser in place for your's Function1DetailViewController in which case you probably are not using storyboard if that's the case, your above implementation  should work without any modification to run under iOS 7.0 as didSelectRowAtIndexPath still behaves as it is meant to.

Comment: I am using storyboards.The problem is it cannot push to the Function1DetailViewController.Moreover, since the tableview do not have the cell inside,I don't know how to draw the segue to link between the two viewcontrollers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been available since iOS2. You will need few changes:

```
if (buttonNum == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Function1Segue" sender:sender];
}
```

Then implement the deleguate method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Function1Segue"])
    {
        // Get reference to Function1DetailViewController
        //Create new Instance here, and set its properties values
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this method. But when I run the apps, after I select from the table, the apps closed. And told me the problem:Thread 1:signal SIGART

Comment: update your post with that code, maybe I can help you find the problem